# QJsonDocument fails with a confusing error

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.7, qjsondocument

Consider the following piece of code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import QJsonDocument

json = {
    "catalog": [
        {
            "version": None,
        },
    ]
}
QJsonDocument(json)
```

Under Python 3.7 and PyQt 5.14.2, it results in the following error at the last line:

`TypeError: a value has type 'list' but 'QJsonValue' is expected`

`QJsonDocument` clearly support lists: `QJsonDocument({'a': []})` works fine.

So, what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the `None` value is the reason. Although the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html#JsonFormat-enum) clearly show that `QJsonDocument` supports `null` values, `None` is not supported in PyQt5: `QJsonDocument({'a': None})` results in

`TypeError: a value has type 'NoneType' but 'QJsonValue' is expected`.

---

The developers explained that that was an omission. They have resolved the issue.